# Firebase dynamic links have started giving the error "Your connection is not private"

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

The FDL has been working fine in production for a few weeks and has suddenly started show this error in the browser as if it does not have a valid SSL certificate.

The FDL is generated via the API.

**Is there a solution to remove this warning for my FDL?**

I have raised a support request with GCP but have posted a question in here in case there is something I can do.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out a received an email from Firebase about this 1 working day ago (before the weekend so I did not notice it).

I followed the instructions and several hours later it was working so I am assuming this was the issue.
Note it did not fix the issue immediately.

> We’re writing to let you know that your Firebase Dynamic Links (FDL)
> project(s) did not have configuration to prevent phishing, so we
> generated Allowlist URLs that your Dynamic Links can redirect to.
>
> Specifying a URL allowlist prevents third parties from using your API
> key to create Dynamic Links that redirect from your FDL domain to
> sites not on the allowlist.
>
> What do I need to do? Review the generated URLs or to add additional
> URLs:
>
> Click 3 dot menu icon> Allowlist URL pattern from the Engage > Dynamic
> Links page of the Firebase console for each project. Review the
> auto-generated allowlist URLs to ensure they cover your intended link
> destinations. [Optional] Specify up to ten regular expressions for
> additional allowed URLs using RE2 syntax. See the images below for
> clarity.
>
> Only URLs that match one of your configured regular expressions can be
> successfully used as a Dynamic Link's deep link or fallback link.
>
> [image]
>
> Your impacted project(s):
>
> project1 project2
>
> To learn more, see the [Allow specific URL patterns documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429).
>
> Feel free to reach out to our Firebase support team for more
> assistance.

Comment: Hi MadMac, In firebase console dynamic Link I am getting following warning  "To increase the security of your project, set your allowed domains for Dynamic Links. Learn more"  when tapping on "Allowlist URL pattern" from 3 dots, I am not getting auto-generated allowlist URLs, we have to add manually over there.

Comment: @MayurMehta In that case you will need to generate your own regular expression. There are a few online tools for this if you google it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue I tried to reproduce:

I can able to reproduce if in My device setting time zone if I set date older then 1 month then this error will come.